# How do I implement user preferences on a PHP jQuery page?

Tags: php, jquery, html

On a portal's main page, I'm using a jQuery container plug-in, and by this users can hide a container by just clicking the minimize button on a container.

My question is: how can I save the user preferences in this regard? Then if the same user logs in again, I want to show the page based on user preferences. For example if a user hides the "sports news container" it won't be shown on users next visit.

Comment: You'll need to use cookies to store a cookie for the user's selection, then upon pageload, read the cookie to decide whether to show the container's contents or not.

Comment: @BraedenP, your solution won't work with login/logout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create a field in the users database table (or do something more complicated, if your database is complicated).

Then you can, if the field is set, place a script on the page that hides the container. And set a callback on hiding/opening which will send an Ajax request to your application, which will set the field to 1 or 0 (ON or OFF, whatever).

Answer (score 1):

I think there are basically 3 options.

Cookies (sending a cookie to the user with JavaScript/jQuery or PHP (setcookie())) and hope the cookie is stored as long as possible.

Storing the preference at the database level, per user. @valya gave a solution like that. The obvious drawback here is that every user of the site, that you want to have preferences, needs a login.

Storing the preference in the database by [IP address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address). This solution is pretty bad, but depending on your users this might work. So you store preferences per IP address. Users with a dynamic IP address or multiple users on the same IP address will have a bad experience.

Comment: `$_SESSION` variables are only stored for that browser session. Once the browser closes or restarts, those `$_SESSION` variables are destroyed.